# how to capture images and post using json in android

Tags: android, web-services, camera

**I have two url, one for post captured image name and second for store image on that location. Now i finished process of open camera. When i take photo then image is stored on DCIM/CAMARA on device phone memory directory. But image is not post and store on two different url. What can i do for that?**

**Code for Open Camara**

```
 btn_camera = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_camera);
         btn_camera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                 startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE); 

//               post(Image_URL, null);

            }
        });
```

**>  Code for Post data on url**

> ```
> try{
>                       ArrayList<NameValuePair> mNameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
>                       mNameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lid", lotids));
>                       mNameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("aid", attandant_id));
>                       mNameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vnum", vehicle_number));
>                       mNameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imag", "xyz"));
>
>                       Log.i("NameValuePair","" + mNameValuePair);
>
>                       result = mCommonClass.PostConnection(Issue_Summons_Url, mNameValuePair);
>                       Log.i("result for log",""+ result);
>
>                   }
>                   catch (Exception e) {
>                       // TODO: handle exception
>                       e.printStackTrace();
>                       Log.e("FastPark App","Nothing to be display");
>                   }
> ```

Comment: no one can have answer for this post???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            switch (requestCode) {
    // get image from camera
            case REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA_IMAGE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // Uri cameraImageUri = data.getData();
                    Log.e("", "camera uri= " + Uri.fromFile(getFile()));
    String path=getFile().getAbsolutePath();
prepareTouploadImage(path);

                }
                break;
    default;
    break;
```

}

use this...in your main activity...u can get path from image

Answer (score 0):

you can find the uri of the file from the camera intent and convert it to a binary data and upload it to the web service
[How to upload a image to server using HttpPost in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152159/how-to-upload-a-image-to-server-using-httppost-in-android) ,or if you want to store it in a different location other than in DCIM/CAMERA you can refer this webpage http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: convert the image to binary in the on activity result function and invoke an async task by passing this binary data to it,i mean the code to post the image should be in the asynctask

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            switch (requestCode) {
    // get image from camera
            case REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA_IMAGE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // Uri cameraImageUri = data.getData();
                    Log.e("", "camera uri= " + Uri.fromFile(getFile()));
    String path=getFile().getAbsolutePath();
prepareTouploadImage(path);

                }
                break;
    default;
    break;
```

this path return your camera image path..
and this path will be posted in json.

```
/**
     * encodes image to string using Base64
     * 
     * @return
     */
    private String prepareTouploadImage(String profileImagePath) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(profileImagePath, options);
        bitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 50, 50, true);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, baos);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);


        byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();

        String imageString = com.eg_lifestyle.utils.Base64
                .encodeBytes(byteArray);
        bitmap = null;
        System.gc();
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        return imageString;
    }
```

this above method returns image converted to binary and return string

Comment: using this path, will image store in particular folder on server?

Comment: we can not maintain server side path from android.we can upload images in binary formate .
this is maintain server side which folder is store in images?

Comment: There are two url one for store image and other for post image name.I want to store image on "http://iblazing.net/fast_park/images/number_plate/" and post image name on "http://iblazing.net/fast_park/index.php?r=webservice/lotregister".

Comment: when i use onActivityResult() then getFile and REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA_IMAGE occures errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void doFileUpload(){
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    DataInputStream inStream = null; 
    String exsistingFileName = "/sdcard/six.3gp";
    // Is this the place are you doing something wrong.
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
    String urlString = "http://192.168.1.5/upload.php";
    try
    {
        Log.e("MediaPlayer","Inside second Method");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(exsistingFileName) );
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Allow Outputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        // Don't use a cached copy.
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        // Use a post method.
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
        dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + exsistingFileName +"\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        Log.e("MediaPlayer","Headers are written");
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            tv.append(inputLine);
        // close streams
        Log.e("MediaPlayer","File is written");
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException ex)
    {
        Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
    }

    //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
    try {
        inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
        String str;            
        while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
        {
            Log.e("MediaPlayer","Server Response"+str);
        }
        /*while((str = inStream.readLine()) !=null ){

        }*/
        inStream.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioex){
        Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
    }
```

use this function....i hope its useful to you to store images in specific folder on server

Comment: where to call this function?

Comment: this fucntion is call in anywhere in your activity.but please put this function in thread.

Comment: some errors are display using this function like "/sdcard/20131206_094126.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)"

Comment: please put your sdcard path of image.

Comment: When i use "String exsistingFileName = "/sdcard/20131206_094126.jpg";" then error is display. Actually, when i capture image then that image store on server means url.

Comment: capture image store in your phone memory..so put that path

Comment: My images are stored on DCIM/CAMERA. but i dont know path for that now what i can do for that?

Comment: when i use capture path like "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/20131206_094126.jpg" then following error is display on logcat "12-06 11:17:05.962: E/MediaPlayer(15963): error: http://iblazing.net/fast_park/images/number_plate/
12-06 11:17:05.962: E/MediaPlayer(15963): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://iblazing.net/fast_park/images/number_plate/
12-06 11:17:05.962: E/MediaPlayer(15963):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)

Comment: "dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + exsistingFileName +"\"" + lineEnd);" Is this for folder directory, which i want to store images on server?